# How to match any pattern by ignoring any special character in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I am writing a grok pattern for switch log. I am not getting how to ignore the "%" character form the log `%DAEMON-3-SYSTEM_MSG`

Complete log is-

```
Jul 16 21:06:50 %DAEMON-3-SYSTEM_MSG: Un-parsable frequency in /mnt/pss/ntp.drift
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the plain `%` character. A not very efficient example:

```
%%{NOTSPACE:switch_source}: %{GREEDYDATA:switch_message}
```

Which will set:

```
{
  "switch_source": [
    [
      "DAEMON-3-SYSTEM_MSG"
    ]
  ],
  "switch_message": [
    [
      "Un-parsable frequency in /mnt/pss/ntp.drift"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The percent-sign is not a special character in Oniguruma regex, so you don't have to escape it. When used with `%{` and then `}` later, that's when you run into problems. But your log-snippet doesn't seem to use that pattern.

Comment: Thanks @sysadmin1138.